# C++, OPENGL and translate() function which throws an error for its arguments

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm concerned mainly with glm library.
I want to translate a vector+matrix, using glm::translate, but it throws errors:

I have the following code:

```
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <GL\glew.h>
#include <GL\GLU.h>
#include <GL\glut.h>
#include <glm.hpp>
#include <GL\gl.h>
#include <gtx\transform2.hpp>
#include <GLFW\glfw3.h>



using namespace std;
using namespace glm;

int main()
{
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n");
        return -1;
    }



    // defining the matrices
    glm::mat4 myMatrix = glm::translate(10f,0.0f,0.0f);
    glm::vec4 myVector(10.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f, 0.0f);
    glm::vec4 transformedVector = myMatrix * myVectors; // multiplication  

    return 0;
}
```

When I execute the code, I get the following errors:

```
error C2059: syntax error : 'bad suffix on number'
error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'f'
error C2784: 'glm::detail::tmat4x4<T,P> glm::translate(const glm::detail::
tvec3<T,P> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const glm::detail::tvec3<T,P> &' from 'int'
```

and a bunch of more errors.

Using the @lazyCoder's solution, I eliminated many errors. Though, I get an error about glm::translate() which is about arguments:

```
 error C2780: 'glm::detail::tmat4x4<T,P> glm::translate(const glm::detail::tvec3<T,P> &)
' : expects 1 arguments - 3 provided
    1>          c:\opengl\glm-0.9.5.4\glm\glm\gtx\transform.hpp(61) : see declaration of
 'glm::translate'

    error C2780: 'glm::detail::tmat4x4<T,P> glm::translate(const glm::detail::tmat4x4<T,P>   
 &,const glm::detail::tvec3<T,P> &)' : expects 2 arguments - 3 provided    
    1>          c:\opengl\glm-0.9.5.4\glm\glm\gtc\matrix_transform.hpp(86) : see declaration of 'glm::translate'
```

Comment: 1. Use forward slashes instead of backslashes in the `#include` directives - you're actually using the escape sequences `\t` once. 2. Those errors come from *compiling* the code, not *executing* it. Please indicate on which lines they occur as well.

Comment: as insane as is sounds try `10.0f` as first argument of the translate. According to the compile error it seems the MS compiler does not recognize the the `10f` as proper `float` and interprets it as an `int`

Comment: @lazycoder It's not even crazy, it's proper C++. A *floating-literal* needs either a *fractional-constant* or an *exponent-part* - so it must contain either `.` or `e`/`E`. You should turn your comment into an answer. Just note that the last `0` is optional - it can just be `10.f`.

Comment: @lazycode, your solution eliminated 80% of the errors. Now I get error for the line which is `expects 1 arguments - 4 provided` and it is related to `glm::translate()` line

Comment: @MostafaTalebi could you update the question with the new errors

Comment: @Angew agreed that it's proper c++, but actually did not realize the compiler are still that picky. I just tried it with gcc and also get an error, better worded though. I guess I didn't make that kind of error in a long time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

replace the first argument of the `translate`  call with `10.f` the compiler complains about an improper suffix on the number, or to quote the g++ error message `invalid suffix "f" on integer constant`

follow up to the consecutive error I don't now glm but it seems that `translate` takes a `vec3` as input and not 3 arguments so try

```
translate(glm::vec3(10.f, 0.f, 0.f))
```

Comment: does not solve. I still get this error: `expects 1 arguments - 3 provided`

Comment: I updated the answer to take the follow up into account.

Comment: thank you man. This was the real solution. I saw it in the translate() declaration, but I could not figure out the solution though. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

This may be a recent change (using glm 9.61 I believe), and I don't know if it's relevant for this discussion anymore, but glm::translate() appears to take arguments glm::mat4x4 and glm::vec3 respectively.

Thusly, when I had a similar error as above I changed my expression from

```
glm::translate(10.f,0.f,0.f)
```

to

```
glm::translate(glm::mat4x4(),glm::vec3(10.f,0.f,0.f)).
```